# Sort arrays with out merging

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I have a data-set which contains more than two arrays. I would like to sort the data-set with out merging the arrays to a single array.

Arrays may or may not be in same machine. I am looking for an efficient way to sort the data.

Comment: How are you going to store the output? distributed again?

Comment: yes, distributed arrays

Comment: There are some researches about this. [here a lecture note](https://stanford.edu/~rezab/classes/cme323/S17/notes/lecture10/cme323_lec10.pdf)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting